# PHP auto urlencode of query string

Tags: php, string, laravel, urlencode

Is there any php.ini directive that enable auto urlencode?

When submit form on local server, i get:

```
filter%5Bdate_from%5D=&filter%5Bdate_to%5D=
```

But on production server the same code get urlencoded query:

```
filter%255Bdate_from%255D=&filter%255Bdate_to%255D=
```

If the code is similar, then there are server settings, right?

Comment: It seems like it url_encode twice, please check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16094418/6028607

Comment: Where it can be encoded twice?

Comment: I don't know exactly but `filter%255Bdate_from%255D=&filter%255Bdate_to%255D=` is the url_encode of `filter%5Bdate_from%5D=&filter%5Bdate_to%5D=`

Comment: Yep, the problem was in second .htaccess file